# Xcode 12: How to get a full window console?

Tags: console, window, xcode12

While working in Xcode, I usually keep a separate window open for just the console so I can see as many lines of output as possible. I just updated to Xcode 12 today, and prior to updating, you could just drag the divider between the editor pane and the console pane up over the editor pane and the console would extend upward to cover the editor (the editor pane would be removed) and you'd have a window that was entirely console space.

However, in Xcode 12, the divider just gets stuck at a certain height and won't go any further up. I've tried Googling around and browsing through the menus and preferences that seem relevant, but I can't find anything that lets you remove the editor pane from a window.

This is a screenshot of what my window looks like (extra small so the screenshot is smaller, but the issue still applies). The gray tool bar just above the output text can normally be dragged upward to make the editor pane disappear, but what is shown in the screenshot is as high as it goes. If I make the window as tall as my screen allows, then the editor pane still takes up about 1/4 -1/5 of the total height, which is exceptionally annoying to not be able to remove.

[image: one editor pane]

I also noticed that if you press the "box with the plus" button in the top right, it'll spawn a new editor pane, and at that point all the editor panes suddenly get X buttons in their top left corners letting you delete individual editor panes, but the moment you get down to only one editor pane, its X button disappears.

[image: two editor panes]

Is there any way to remove that last editor pane so that the console takes up the entire window? It seems like this would be a fairly common thing to do, so I'd be surprised if they removed the ability to do so.

Comment: nobody? I'd like to know this too.

Comment: Yes, this really bothers me, wondering why they did that

Comment: There's also a discussion on Apple developer website: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660881
But seems nobody cares :P

Comment: I've filed a feedback: FB8815949 just hope they'll see it

Comment: Open radar: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4933204356104192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm this issue has been fixed in Xcode latest beta (Xcode 12.2 beta 4 12B5044c)

Guys just go update Xcode!

Answer (score 0):

For me an Xcode update didn't do it, however, update to Big Sur did!